# how to loop through an array and string

Tags: php, arrays, json, api

I am trying to get some data from an api and loop through a set of arrays but I am unable to do so as it is keep giving an error i.e Notice: Array to string conversion

My code is:

```
<?php

    $url  = 'myapiurl';
    $curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "",
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            "accept: application/json",
            "cache-control: no-cache",
            "content-type: application/json"
        ),
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $err      = curl_error($curl);

    curl_close($curl);

    if ($err) {
        echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
    } 
    else {
        $characters = json_decode($response, true);
        $x          =  ($characters["data"]);

        echo $x;
        // print_r($x);
        //var_dump($characters);
    }
?>
```

Var_dump result:

```
array(4) { ["data"]=> array(6) { [0]=> array(5) { ["ticket_status_id"]=> string(1) "0" ["ticket_id"]=> string(5) "28597" ["priority_id"]=> string(1) "0" ["created_at"]=> string(19) "2018-05-17 15:46:07" ["status_changed_at"]=> NULL } [1]=> array(5) { ["ticket_status_id"]=> string(1) "5" ["ticket_id"]=> string(5) "28598" ["priority_id"]=> string(1) "0" ["created_at"]=> string(19) "2018-05-17 15:49:07" ["status_changed_at"]=> string(19) "2018-05-17 10:21:21" } [2]=> array(5) { ["ticket_status_id"]=> string(1) "0" ["ticket_id"]=> string(5) "28668" ["priority_id"]=> string(1) "0" ["created_at"]=> string(19) "2018-05-18 09:47:28" ["status_changed_at"]=> NULL } [3]=> array(5) { ["ticket_status_id"]=> string(1) "0" ["ticket_id"]=> string(5) "28669" ["priority_id"]=> string(1) "0" ["created_at"]=> string(19) "2018-05-18 09:47:48" ["status_changed_at"]=> NULL } [4]=> array(5) { ["ticket_status_id"]=> string(1) "5" ["ticket_id"]=> string(5) "29036" ["priority_id"]=> string(1) "3" ["created_at"]=> string(19) "2018-05-22 12:13:03" ["status_changed_at"]=> string(19) "2018-05-22 06:43:51" } [5]=> array(5) { ["ticket_status_id"]=> string(1) "5" ["ticket_id"]=> string(5) "29037" ["priority_id"]=> string(1) "3" ["created_at"]=> string(19) "2018-05-22 12:15:29" ["status_changed_at"]=> NULL } } ["code"]=> int(200) ["error"]=> string(5) "false" ["message"]=> string(7) "Success" }
```

Json response:

```
{"data":[{"ticket_status_id":"0","ticket_id":"28597","priority_id":"0","created_at":"2018-05-17 15:46:07","status_changed_at":null},{"ticket_status_id":"5","ticket_id":"28598","priority_id":"0","created_at":"2018-05-17 15:49:07","status_changed_at":"2018-05-17 10:21:21"},{"ticket_status_id":"0","ticket_id":"28668","priority_id":"0","created_at":"2018-05-18 09:47:28","status_changed_at":null},{"ticket_status_id":"0","ticket_id":"28669","priority_id":"0","created_at":"2018-05-18 09:47:48","status_changed_at":null},{"ticket_status_id":"5","ticket_id":"29036","priority_id":"3","created_at":"2018-05-22 12:13:03","status_changed_at":"2018-05-22 06:43:51"},{"ticket_status_id":"5","ticket_id":"29037","priority_id":"3","created_at":"2018-05-22 12:15:29","status_changed_at":null}],"code":200,"error":"false","message":"Success"}
```

How to echo ticket_id and created_at from this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Comment: @Mehdi This is totally different I am not asking about error , I am asking as how to loop through this structure so that I can get proper result

Comment: @AzadAlam Can you edit your question and post the JSON response you get as well?

Comment: What @Mehdi has posted will tell you why you get that error and how to fix it.

Comment: `$characters["data"]` is an Array. `echo $characters["data"][0]['ticket_status_id']`

Comment: Thanks @hungrykoala. How to get last column without defining index or how to get each data that is present under ticket_status_id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach($data as $key => $value) {
   echo $value["ticket_id"];
   echo "<br/>";
   echo $value["created_at"];
}
```